# Почему неправильное написание глаголов с двумя Т на конце стало очень распространено?

Tags: орфография, глаголы

В последнее время всё чаще замечаю, что пользователи интернета всё чаще допускают ошибки в написании глаголов: пишут на конце глаголов две буквы Т вместо ТЬ, к примеру, "Сдела**тт**" вместо правильного "сдела**ть**".

Comment: Может, потому, что две клавиши рядом находятся?